# how to add a different css to last mysql query result using php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm retrieving 4 latest items from the database and show them in a list. My question is that how can I add a different HTML class to the last item?! for example,

```
<ul>
    <li class="list">number 1</li>
    <li class="list">number 2</li>
    <li class="list">number 3</li>
    <li class="list last-child">number 4</li> 
</ul>
```

how can I add **last-child** to the last item using php?

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148116/php-sql-query-find-last-result/20148204#20148204) this is for demo how you can identify the last record in loop

Comment: Those are HTML classes, not CSS classes. There is no such thing as a CSS class. If you want to apply a CSS rule to the last item in a list, then you don't need to use a class to identify it, CSS has the [`:last-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of assigning a class using PHP, use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo instead

```
ul.class_name li:last-child { /* This will target last li in the ul */
   /* Styles */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ63R/)

Better assign a `class` to your `ul` element to distinguish with other `ul` elements in the same document.

---

If you want to literally add the `class` to the DOM for some reason than you can use a counter variable with `mysqli_num_rows` (Here I assume you are atleast using `mysqli_()`).

```
$counter = 0;
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while($throw_results = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $counter++; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
   if($total_rows == $counter) {
      /* Add class if total rows = counter value */
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course my ul has got a class. Here, I just wrote a simple code which is not my code. And the way you've mentioned is a very nice way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div>
  <span>John,</span>
  <span>Karl,</span>
  <span>Brandon,</span>
  <span>Sam</span>
</div>

<script>
$( "div span:last-child" )
  .css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" })
  .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "solast" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "solast" );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i= 0;
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);


 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        echo ($i == $total_rows ) ? '<li class="list">number 1</li>
<li class="list">number 2</li>
<li class="list">number 3</li>
<li class="list last-child">number 4</li> ' :'<li class="list">number 1</li>
<li class="list">number 2</li>
<li class="list">number 3</li>
<li class="list">number 4</li> ';
        $i++;
    }
```